# Angular2 application strips equalto from path params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an application where an user gets an email link which open my angular2 application.

I attach an encoded token to my URL.

an example of the URL is:
   'http://localhost:4200/#/token/dGVzdEBlbWFpbC5jb20='

However, the URL automatically gets converted into:
 'http://localhost:4200/#/token/dGVzdEBlbWFpbC5jb20'

once the angular2 app loads. And as a result the decoding fails.
How can I stop angular2 application from removing the equals to from the URL?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "=" character is reserved within a query component and have special meaning within a URI/URL
May be try passing token as query param

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not the culprit here, the equal sign is reserved in a URL. I assume your doing something similar to HttpUtilities.Encode or Server.Encode on the server side? In either case it's probably better to go with a ASCII version:

Please replace the '=' sign with '&#61'.